# Solving for limiting distribution in a Markov chain with finite states and continuous time

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, matlab

I have formulated a problem as a finite-state continuous time Markov chain. I have the infinitesimal generator matrix, which I'll call $\mathbf{A}$, of the form

$
\mathbf{A} =
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & \dots  & q_{1N}  \\
\vdots     & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{N1}      & \dots       & q_{NN} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Where the $q_{ii}$ terms along the diagonal represent the parameters of the exponential distribution describing the sojourn time in the $i^{th}$ state (equal to the negative sum of the other rates in the row). The formula in my textbook for the limiting distribution, $\mathbf{\pi}$, of a Markov chain of this form is

$\mathbf{\pi} \mathbf{A} = 0$

where $\pi_i$ is the equilibrium proportion of time spent in the $i^{th}$ state. I am implementing this model in MATLAB, and would like to use this equation to verify. To do so I have

```
b = zeros(1,N);
pi = A'\b';
```

This doesn't work as MATLAB complains that the matrix is singular. I then tried every trick in the book for working with matrices that are close to singular, to no avail. I then asked my professor, and his answer was simply that the generator matrix should be singular, as it has one dominant eigenvalue of zero, and that I should just solve the system.

How do I solve this system if the matrix is singular?

Comment: that's for transition probabilities, this is an infinitesimal generator matrix, not a transition probability matrix

Comment: I guess you could use [`null`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. The equation

$\mathbf{\pi}\mathbf{A} =\mathbf{0}$

is just a left eigenvector equation for eigenvalue 0. In MATLAB can be found with

```
[V,D,W] = eig(A)
```

where W is the left eigenvectors.